# Network and Graph theory problem

Tags: algorithm, network-programming

You have N computers and [Ca, Cb] means a is connected to b and this connectivity is symmetric and transitive.  The problem is to write a program which checks that all computers are interconnected and talk to each other.

A time efficient algorithm is preferable.

Comment: You should flag this as homework

Comment: @Tristram: I flagged it `possible-homework` for him...

Comment: @SIVA, what have you done to solve the problem, and what problems are you having with your solution?

Answer (score 5):

This is called [Graph Connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29). Read about it and you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Any search of the graph that doesn't traverse a node multiple times should be sufficient.  There are many options:
http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Graph_Connectivity
I would probably pick DFS or BFS.

Answer (score 1):

because you say that A time efficient algorithm is preferable.thus DFS is the best algorithm for U..notice that size of your edge in network computer is small
dfs :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search